# SQL query to combine column data from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x

SQL Server 2012, Python 3.

Background Info:

I have two tables; LOADS and FACTORS.

1. LOADS has the following columns:

[image: LOADS table]

2. FACTORS has the following columns:

[image: FACTORS table]

3. Table FACTORS is basically a roadmap how to combine and factor the data in table LOADS.
4. FACTORS columns `mlc` and `tlc` contain the same numbers as LOADS table column `subcase`.
5. In this example we will only use value `32771` for `LOADS` column `eid`.

Problem:

I need to get a set of results with columns similar to LOADS but with additional columns, like this:
`eid, mlc, tlc, fx, fy, fz`.

To do this manually:

1. start with the first row of `FACTORS`. `mlc`=`1053002`, `tlc`=`4053400`
2. `select fx, fy, fz from LOADS where subcase=mlc and eid=32771` (this is our mlc loads)
3. `select fx, fy, fz from LOADS where subcase=tlc and eid=32771` (this is our tlc loads)
4. the final values in columns `fx, fy, fz` are from these equation:

   `(mlc.fx * mf + tlc.fx * tf) * cf`

   `(mlc.fy * mf + tlc.fy * tf) * cf`

   `(mlc.fz * mf + tlc.fz * tf) * cf`
5. If `tlc=0` then only use `mlc`. The `fx, fy, fz` values are from these equations:

   `(mlc.fx * mf) * cf`

   `(mlc.fy * mf) * cf`

   `(mlc.fz * mf) * cf`

I am somewhere between beginner and intermediate using SQL so I have no idea how to do this using only SQL. I have successfully done this using `pandas` basically doing this the manual way by creating a blank DataFrame, calculating the (3) DOF `fx,fy,fz` and adding Rows one at a time, building the DataFrame from the ground up. I *can* share that code if anyone needs to see it, but I really want to do this in SQL if it's possible. The reason is because most general queries using this procedure can take several minutes (for 50,000+ Rows,  granted my pandas knowledge might not be too efficient for real world usage) and I really want to get that time down to a few seconds.

Comment: The sample data doesn't seem to show any matches on `subcase=mlc` or `subcase=tlc`, but ignoring that, what you're describing seems to just require selecting from factors and joining to the loads table twice. If this is going too slowly, it might help to, say, put an (unique?) index on subcase/eid and mlc/tlc

Comment: @ZLK both tables have thousands of rows with many matches, that was just a sample. I don't understand what you mean by joining to the loads table twice. Is this your interpretation of how to do what I described in points 4, 5 above? I should mention the factors are not always Integers, they are dimensioned as Floats.

Comment: In step 2 of your manual steps, you look up from LOADS table using the mlc and eid. Where does the eid come from? As far as I see you don't have eid until you have looked it up in LOADS??

Comment: In future please use tables of parsable data instead of images of data, then we can build tables to test with. (Just imagine how frustrating it would be if our answers were images of queries.)

Comment: @TomC. The eid comes from getting a unique list from LOADS eid column. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Point taken. I would have, but didn't know how to. I will make sure to do so in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Data: Just copy paste, indent each row  4 spaces so it formats as code. There is an {} icon in the toolbar that can be used to do the indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ZLK's comment, it seems like you want this:

```
select
  LoadsMlc.eid,
  Factors.mlc,
  Factors.tlc,
  (LoadsMlc.fx * Factors.mf + isnull(LoadsTlc.fx * Factors.tf, 0)) * Factors.cf fx,
  (LoadsMlc.fy * Factors.mf + isnull(LoadsTlc.fy * Factors.tf, 0)) * Factors.cf fy,
  (LoadsMlc.fz * Factors.mf + isnull(LoadsTlc.fz * Factors.tf, 0)) * Factors.cf fz
from
  dbo.Factors
  join dbo.Loads LoadsMlc on Factors.mlc = LoadsMlc.subcase
  left outer join dbo.Loads LoadsTlc on nullif(Factors.tlc, 0) = LoadsTlc.subcase
```

This assumes there exists exactly one match for subcase against `mlc`--your question doesn't currently indicate one way or another. You may want to, perhaps, add something like

```
where
   LoadsTlc.eid is null -- We didn't find a tlc (it was 0)
   or LoadsMlc.eid = LoadsTlc.eid
```

If there are potentially multiple matches across the Loads table for each of the Factors. Note that the `tlc` join is a left outer, as you indicated that we should only use `mlc` in the case that it is 0.

The second join to `Loads` uses a `nullif` to nullify the case when `tlc` is 0. In that case you'll receive no records for that value. The three columns account for this null case by adding 0.